# <TableRow> styles not applying to <TableCell>

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change fontWeight for every cell under `<TableRow>`, so applied "fontWeight" on `<TableRow>` hoping that this style will apply to every cell inside it. But it's not happening.

// demo.js

```js
<TableRow sx={{ fontWeight: "300" }}> {/*  Not applied to table cells under this tag*/}
  <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: "300" }}> {/* Applying successfully */}
    Dessert (100g serving)
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Applying `fontWeight` for `<TableCell>` is working, but why is styles applied on `<TableRow>` not effecting it's children?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-table-row-font-weight-sofl-yk6t9o) Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `<th>` by default has `font-weight: 500`. **You have to override it**. If you want them to inherit, you can do: `font-weight: inherit;` to TableCell

Children inherit style from parent, only if it does not have that style applied in self

Comment: I tried  
     <TableRow
            sx={{
              "& .MuiTableRow-root": {
                fontWeight: "300"
              }
            }}
          >
it's not working. you can check sandbox.

Comment: the correct selector is not 'MuiTableRow-root', but 'MuiTableCell-root'

Comment: I thought you asked to override `<th>` which is `MuiTableRow-root` so that those styles will apply to it's children.  
If I need to override `MuiTableCell-root`  ie `<TableCell>` , then I Have to apply each cell with that style. 

In that case, I can style each `<TableCell>`  using either sx or className, with normal CSS ie fontWeight:300 on each cell.

Comment: I explained you in my answer why 'is styles applied on <TableRow> not effecting it's children?'. When an element has specific style in self, applying same style with different value in parent wont affect the children. <th> already has font-weight, you can not override it just by selecting a parent. Children inherit style from parent, only if it does not have that style applied in self